# Finding value of lower bound of an integral given an equation with a constant term equal to that bound

Tags: integration, functions

I need help with the first part of [this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ppe9k.png). I am studying for an exam but cannot solve this question. 
Consider the function $$F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt=x^3-2x^2+x-a$$ for $a \ne 0$. Find $a$.

Now, given the same function how do I find: $$f(x)$$

Comment: The answer for 2. (1) is a=2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that
$$
0=F(a)=\int_a^a f(t)\, dt=a^3-2a^2
$$
Using the fact that $a\neq 0$, one can factor and solve the above equation for $a$.

Comment: Why is F(a) = 0? Could you illustrate this with another example or such?

Comment: Never mind. I see why. It's because of the integral. Then it would only make sense if a=2. Thanks!